# How to detect when Lagging Span / Chikou Span is above the clouds and candles in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I'm using the CM_Enhanced_Ichimoku Cloud-V5.2 indicator and I want to plotchar when the Tenkan-Sen line and Kijun-Sen line cross below Chikou Span (lagging span) if the Chikou Span (lagging span) is above the clouds and candle

if the Chikou Span (lagging span) is above the clouds and candle, plotchar should display a char when the Tenkan-Sen line and Kijun-Sen line cross below Chikou Span (lagging span)

Comment: Are you able to code the Ichimoku Cloud yourself?

Comment: Thanks! I am tweaking the existing the code@baris-yakut